# Can I refer to a Python class prefixed by its package?

Tags: python

I have some Python modules inside packages, like so:

```
root/
  airplane/
    __init__.py
    propeller.py # defines class Propeller
    engine.py    # defines class Engine
  boat/
    __init__.py
    engine.py    # defines class Engine
```

I'd like to refer to the class constructors (or other class/static methods) prefixed with the package to avoid ambiguity:

```
airplaneEngine = airplane.Engine('4 cylinder')
boatEngine     = boat.Engine('6 cylinder')
if boatEngine.isFasterThan(airplaneEngine): print('Boat wins!')
```

But I can't get the imports to work correctly.

```
from airplane import engine
airplaneEngine = airplane.Engine('4 cylinder') 
# NameError: name 'airplane' is not defined

from airplane.engine import Engine
airplaneEngine = airplane.Engine('4 cylinder') 
# NameError: name 'airplane' is not defined
```

I realize I can do this:

```
from airplane.engine import Engine as AirplaneEngine
airplaneEngine = AirplaneEngine('4 cylinder')
```

Or this:

```
root/
  airplane.py # defines class Propeller & class Engine
  boat.py     # defines class Engine

import airplane
airplaneEngine = airplane.Engine('4 cylinder')
```

But I'm not loving either of those solutions. Is there a way to refer to the static/class methods prefixed by the package?

Answer (score 1):

```
from airplane import engine
airplaneEngine = airplane.Engine('4 cylinder') 
# NameError: name 'airplane' is not defined

from airplane.engine import Engine
airplaneEngine = airplane.Engine('4 cylinder') 
# NameError: name 'airplane' is not defined
```

should be

```
from airplane import engine
airplaneEngine = engine.Engine('4 cylinder') 

from airplane.engine import Engine
airplaneEngine = Engine('4 cylinder')
```

In the first attempt, you are importing the `engine` file and can refer to the classes within it. You have not imported `airplane`, just the file within that folder.

In the second attempt, you are importing the `Engine` class, but again have not imported `airplane`. Additionally, the `Engine` class doesn't belong to `airplane`, it lives in `engine.py`

Comment: So ... not possible then? Neither `engine.Engine` or just `Engine` achieves the (self-documenting) namespacing I want here (`airplane.Engine`). The only way I see is to define all the classes I want to refer to this way (`Engine`, `Propellor`) inside the single file `airplane.py`.

Comment: I guess you could make an `airplane.py` file within airplane and import/instantiate each class there. Then you could do `from airplane import airplane` then refer to them as `airplane.engine`. The airplane.py file would essentially have `import engine` at the top then `Engine = engine.Engine()`

Comment: Yes! If I put `Engine = engine.Engine` (without the parens) inside `airplane/airplane.py` then I can construct one as `airplane.Engine(...)` as desired.